# Finding a linear transformation $L$ such that $ L(\vec{u}_{i}) = {v}_{i}$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq 3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been tearing my hair out for hours over this seemingly straightforward linear question. I know it's bad form to post homework without some partial amount of work done, but my work is garbage. I think I'm misunderstanding this question very badly and would appreciate a sanity check.

Define these six vectors:

$$ \vec{u}_{1} = (1,4,7,2) \qquad \vec{u}_{2} = (3,1,1,5) \qquad \vec{u}_{3} = (-3,10,19,-4) $$

$$ \vec{v}_{1} = (7,1,6,5) \qquad \vec{v}_{2} = (-2,1,3,1) \qquad \vec{v}_{3} = (11,3,2,9) $$

Find a linear transformation $L$ such that $ L(\vec{u}_{i}) = {v}_{i}$  for $ 1 \leq i \leq 3$.

(Hint: write down the three equations $L(\vec{u}_{i}) = {v}_{i}$ in terms of the columns of the coefficient matrix of $L$. This will be a system of three equations with four $vectors.$ Find four vectors that satisfy this system.)

Comment: It is **extremely rude** to vandalize your own question, even more if two people took the time to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible.

Note that $u_3 = 3 u_1-2 u_2$. Hence we should have $v_3=L(u_3) = 3 L(u_1)-2 L(u_2) = 3 v_1-2 v_2$.

However, it is easy to check that this is not the case, hence no such linear transformation exists.

(Possibly there is a transcription error?)

Comment: You're right. There must be a transcription error, so that the $u_k$ (as actually stated) are linearly independent.

Comment: I thought I was messing up the substitution, and I couldn't understand how four vectors could satisfy the system.

I double-checked, and it's written the same way in the book. Ouh.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, let me take the elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be column vectors, and in particular replace the $u_k$'s and $v_k$'s by their transposes, the corresponding column vectors.

Well, let $L : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be your linear transformation, and let $A$ be the matrix of $L$ with respect to the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$; let $A_k \in \mathbb{R}^4$ be the $k$-th column of $A$, $k=1,\dotsc,4$. Then for each $k$, by unpacking the matrix multiplication, one can check that
$$
 v_k = L(u_k) = A u_k = (u_k)_1 A_1 + (u_k)_2 A_2 + (u_k)_3 A_3 + (u_k)_4 A_4,
$$
where $(u_k)_j$ denotes the $j$th entry of $u_k$. Plugging your given $u_k$ and $v_k$ gives the hinted-at system of three linear equations in four unknown vectors.

Comment: They were actually supposed to be column vectors already, I think. My instructor uses commas for column vectors and none for row vectors, but this was taken out of a textbook so I wasn't entirely sure.

I had gotten as far as that before, but I got tripped up with dimensionality. I end up with a 3 x 4 matrix, but I'm unclear on how the augment should work. Do I just use $\vec{u}_{1}, \, \vec{u}_{2}, $and$\, \vec{u}_{3}$ on the right hand side?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, your three equations would be
$$
 (u_k)_1 A_1 + (u_k)_2 A_2 + (u_k)_3 A_3 + (u_k)_4 A_4 = v_k
$$
for $k=1$, $2$, $3$. This'll give you a perfectly reasonable system of linear equations, but it'll fail to be consistent precisely for the reason copper.hat pointed out. Given that the problem clearly presupposes the existence of $L$, something must have gone very, very wrong in the typesetting...